# Configuring: TIBCO EMS Transport Channel for WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, tibco, tibco-ems, ems

Has anybody used EMS WCF plugin (Net.Tems Listener Adapter)?

How can I configure number of listeners to the
queue or topic, threading/max jobs/flow control and keep alive.. settings in my WCF service?

I have a working WCF service listening to XML SOAP over JMS binding hosted with WAS (Net.Tems Listener Adapter) in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by controlling the IIS application pool configuration. (Idle timeout, worker processes..)
Or can be managed by the developer when hosting the WCF service in a custom host instead of IIS.
Otherwise by default there can be only 1 lister for each WCF service (using WAS TEMS based hosting) therefore deploy the service multiple times to have more active listeners.
You may also add the number of worker processes in the IIS application pool but that will be activated as and when IIS find the need for more processes to do the load balancing.